# Enviar 2 Variables en Checkbox (realizando calculo de valores)

Tags: html, mysql, post, checkbox

Como puedo enviar 2 variables php en un checkbox, siendo en el value o alguna otra alternativa?
Mi pregunta se basa en el siguiente problema.
Tengo que enviar el id por post (hasta ahi ningun problema), pero a la vez, tengo un input que recibe el calculo del valor asociado a ese id para mostrarlo en pantalla:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" value="<?=$row['valor']?>" onclick="sume(this)"></td>
  <td align="center" style="font-size:14px; color: #000"><?=$id_venta?></td>
  <td align="center" style="font-size:14px; color: #000"><?=$piso?></td>
  <td align="center" style="font-size:14px; color: #000"><?php echo $row['mesa']?></td>
  <td align="center" style="font-size:14px; color: #000"><?php echo strtoupper($row['sector'])?></td>
  <td align="center" style="font-size:14px; color: #000">$<?php echo $valorn?></td>
  <td align="center" style="font-size:14px; color: #000">$<?=$propina?></td>
  <td align="center" style="font-size:14px; color: #000">$<?php echo $valort?></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>

<div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group text-left mb-0">
  <label for="field-5" class="control-label">MONTO SELECCIONADO</label>
  <input type="text" style="text-align: center" class="form-control" name="tot" id="tot">
 </div>
</div>
```

La otra variable que debo enviar es:

```
<?=$row['id']?>
```

Donde la funcion:

```
<script>
var total = 0;
function sume(pr){
var data = Number(pr.value)
if(!pr.checked) {data *= -1}
 total+= data
 document.getElementById("tot").value = total
}
</script>
```

Hace el calculo de los valores de cada id, ya que deben ser mostrados al cliente antes de enviar el formulario.
Alguna idea de como poder hacer eso?
De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda u orientacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy fácil usa la propiedad data, simplemente definen la propiedad con el prefijo data-.

Es decir si necesitas mandar el idPost  y el valorAsociado tu input quedaria algo asi:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" value="50" data-idpost='5' data-valorasociado='50' onclick="sume(this)">
```

y para leer estos valores es con la propiedad dataset, aqui te dejo un ejemplo práctico espero y te sirva

```js
var total = 0;
function sume(pr){
 var data = Number(pr.value)
 if(!pr.checked) {data *= -1}
  total+= data;
  document.getElementById("tot").value = total;
  
  alert('valorasociado: ' + pr.dataset.valorasociado);
  alert('idpost: ' + pr.dataset.idpost);
  
}
```

```html
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" value="50" data-idpost='5' data-valorasociado='50' onclick="sume(this)"></td>

 </tr>
</tbody>

<div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group text-left mb-0">
  <label for="field-5" class="control-label">MONTO SELECCIONADO</label>
  <input type="text" style="text-align: center" class="form-control" name="tot" id="tot">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: estimado, muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayudarme. era lo que necesitaba. funciona como lo necesito. muchas gracias por su tiempo. saludos.

Comment: De nada, cuando gustes